# Log4j2: Adding certain string to each logged line

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

We are using log4j2 in our tomcat application. We would like to add session ID to each log line (please don't judge us for that, maybe it is not the best thing to do, but it is very practical).

So we would like to achieve something like this:

```
2018-05-08 21:55:20,828 INFO SessionId CurrentClass LogMessage
```

To achieve this, we would need to create some kind of callback for each logged line. Is this feasible with log4j2?

Comment: Does [Log4j2's Thread context](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html) help you? I'm not familiar with it, just know it exists.

Comment: you can wrap your logger in a utility class that accepts a session id and the message and then formats it into one message before sending it `log4j`

Comment: @tima: that is really not a good idea

Comment: @Vojtěch some people do that, in case they change the logger implementation later on to something other than log4j you only have change the wrapper; but it seems like there is an easier solution in your case

Comment: @Vojtěch you can use log4j2 MapMessage and use %K{key} to retrieve your session id. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293213/using-log4j2-how-to-log-key-value-pairs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add any information in your log by doing:

```
String sessionId = "my-session" // this is dynamic.. You can get it in a filter..
org.apache.log4j.MDC.put("sessionId", sessionId);
```

Then, define your log pattern as something like:

```
 %d{ISO8601}] %X{sessionId} %p %c - %m%n
```

After that, the logger will print the sessionId.

Comment: Yes, log4j is thread safe. See: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a1.7

Comment: @ThiagoProcaci is log4j2 thread-safe? Your link is for log4j 1.2